# c# Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1 CustomsearchService suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

9 months ago I implemented a pretty simple image search into a bot for a discord server I run.  It uses Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService to request an image from a string and then randomly picks one of the top 10 results and posts it back.  It's sort of a dumb way for people to do images inline conversations.

Suddenly, this has stopped working, and I'm at a loss.  My code looks as follows:

```
string use_input = "test_image"; // normally passed into function

var service   = new CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {ApiKey = Database.Instance.SearchEngineHash});
var request   = service.Cse.List(use_input);

request.Safe       = CseResource.ListRequest.SafeEnum.Active;
request.Num        = 10;
request.Cx         = Database.Instance.SearchEngineId; // my engine id
request.SearchType = CseResource.ListRequest.SearchTypeEnum.Image;
 
Search request_results = request.Execute();
IList<Result> paging = request_results.Items;
```

There are no errors (that I can understand) generated, but the request_results.Items is null.

request_results.Queries[0].Value[0].TotalResults is 24800, indicating that it totally got *something* back, and if I go to my google API page I see a traffic hit when I do the image search, I just get back null in results.

I've reviewed all my API credentials on console.developers.google.com a jillion times, and everything lines up.  No warnings, and I even see the search traffic go though.  I just get back 0 results.

I have no idea what's going on and I'm hoping someone knows of something that changed very recently that I might not be accounting for.  As it stands, it's just a black box.

Anyone have any idea why the above code worked for months, but now fails to get any result back?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: So, interestingly even my custom search url (https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006456520698995124789:oczuqs0qnkp) can't show images.  It has the same sort of a problem -- the tabbed results list at the bottom demonstrates it has found <X> results, but every page is "no results"  - - - I checked my settings and I have "Search Images" flagged "On" in the CSE.

Comment: Adding to the running narrative for anyone watching along -- there are several other people around the inter-webs reporting the exact same problem.  Sounds like something has changed on Google's side.

Comment: Google has acknowledged the problem is on their side -- you can see one of many threads about it here:  https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/62023509?hl=en

Comment: Appreciate anyone who stopped by to try to help -- I supposed "Google is broken" was less likely then "I've done something wrong" -- sorry if I wasted anyone's time.